# Last id of an Element Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i read the last element id using javascript?

for example :

```
          <div id='print'>

                <p id=1>some data</p>
                <p id=2>some data</p>
                <p id=3>some data</p>
                <p id=4>some data</p>
                <p id=5>some data</p>

          </div>
```

I need to detect the id of last

I need max number of the id actually.it's generated sequentially.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, id values cannot be numbers.  They must start with a non-number.

You can get the last child with this plain javascript (no jQuery required):

```
var lastChild = document.getElementById("print").lastChild;
var lastChildID = lastChild.id;
```

or in one line, it would be this:

```
var lastChildID = document.getElementById("print").lastChild.id
```

FYI, in case you need access to any other children you can always get all the children and then fetch the one you want:

```
var children = document.getElementById("print").children;
if (children.length > 1) {
    var first = children[0];
    var last = children[children.length - 1];
    var second = children[1];
}
```

Now that you've explained what you're really trying to do, I'd suggest this:

```
 <div id='print'>
     <p data-num="1">some data</p>
     <p data-num="2">some data</p>
     <p data-num="3">some data</p>
     <p data-num="4">some data</p>
     <p data-num="5">some data</p>
 </div>
```

And, then this javascript:

```
var lastValue = document.getElementById("print").lastChild.getAttribute("data-num");
```

Using the `data-xxx` format is forward compatible with the HTML5 specification and usable in older browsers with `getAttribute()`.

Comment: i am concerned that it cant be number it's like <p id="1">....like this..let me try your code...

Comment: No, `id="1"` is not allowed by specification.  Make it `id="item1"` or something like that.

Comment: ahh man...i need the max id so that i can check with last value in the database..that's what i am trying to read the last element id..and sending a request with that id with ajax GET

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju - I added onto the end of my answer to show you another way to do this.

Comment: ya i got it this way :var children = document.getElementById("print").children;
    var last = children[children.length - 1];

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
getElementById('print').lastChild.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can simply use their selectors to find this:

```
$("p").last().attr("id");
```

Comment: This won't do the job - if there are more paragraphs in the page, this will get the last one.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you could do something like this `$("div#print :last-child").attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:-

```
$('p:last').attr('id')
```

OR

```
$('div#print p:last').attr('id')
```